# Retrieve actual data from raster with colorbar Python

Tags: python, arrays, plot, colorbar

I know that matplotlib can map data on RGB values. A classic exemple could be values of elevation mapped with the "terrain" cmap from matplotlib.
[Captured from GRASS tutorial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHttz.png)

I have an RGB tiff file corresponding to magnetic anomalies. This is useless because there is actually no data but only RGB values. But... If only I could "reverse", "un-normalize" the RGB values from the colobar to retrieve the data... That would be amazing! Is there a function I do not know in matplotlib (or anything else) to do that?
Like:

def fictionnal_fonction(img=TiffFile, min=min_on_colorbar, max=max_on_colorbar, colormap=viridis):

return greyscale_array_actual_data

Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Thx for your answer. I don t want to invert the colormap (red=max, blue=min <-> red=min, blue=max). I want to get the data "behind" the RGB values of the colormap.

Comment: If I now understand you correctly and you want to retreive values from an image file of a plot. That image file is looking like being generated by matplotlib, but you don't have the code that generaded it (and the data), you only have an image file of a plot. And you want to get data values based on that images colors. Then I'd think matplotlib is the wrong tag.

Comment: Yes that's what I'd like to do! I'll follow your advice and edit the tags.